# SSIS Convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm to ISO8601

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, iso8601

I need to transform a date in a csv file with SSIS, i will not load it into a DB only load it back to the csv.

The date format is; **2019-07-02 04:16**

And I need it to be; **2019-07-02T04:16:29**

I can't find any expression to help me with this and would gladly get some help along the way.

Comment: How `04:16` is converted to `04:16:29` while it is stored in a flat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I will assume that the column data type is DT_STR or DT_WSTR since it is stored in a csv file.*

You can use the following expression to convert from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format to `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`: *(I added `:00` at the end since the is no seconds in the first format)*

```
TOKEN([DateColumn]," ",1) + "T" + TOKEN([DateColumn]," ",2) + ":00"
```

If the Initial column contains the seconds part then just use the following expression:

```
TOKEN([DateColumn]," ",1) + "T" + TOKEN([DateColumn]," ",2)
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed. Thank you. I just had to convert it with help of "Derived Column" function in SSIS and then save it as a new file.